# odeint for time varying excitation

Tags: python, odeint

I want to solve the coupled differential equation. [image]

Here `A` is the excitation and `y(t)` is the response where `y=[y1,y2]`. I wrote the following code that works for a constant, single excitation value. But it fails when I put a time varying excitation. In other words,
my code works for `A=0.5e8`
Doesn't work for `A=1e8*np.sin(np.log10(t))`.
How can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

k=1.381e-23
T=300
V0=1e13


def dpdt(y,t,Wb,V0,A,kT):
    y1=y[0]
    y2=y[1]
    W1=(Wb+0.02*A)*1e-26      
    W2=(Wb-0.02*A)*1e-26      

    w_12=V0*np.exp(-W1/kT)   
    w_21=V0*np.exp(-W2/kT)
    
    
    dP1_dt=- w_12*y1 + w_21*y2
    dP2_dt=+ w_12*y1 - w_21*y2
    dp_dt=[dP1_dt,dP2_dt]     
    return dp_dt
    
y1_0=0.5
Wb=15936297.62 
t=np.logspace(-5,5,100)

A=1e8*np.sin(np.log10(t))  #Doesn't work
A=0.5e8  #Works

p=odeint(dpdt,[y1_0,1-y1_0],t,args=(Wb,V0,A,k*T))

plt.semilogx(t,p[:,0])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `A=1e8*np.sin(np.log10(t))` is a `numpy.ndarray`, because `t` is. You can see this yourself if you evaluate `type(1e8*np.sin(np.log10(t)))`

But the problem is that the function `dpdt` expects `A` to be a scalar (`float`).

You can pull the definition of `A` inside of `dpdt` to fix this, be redefining it as:

```
def dpdt(y,t,Wb,V0,kT):
    y1=y[0]
    y2=y[1]
    A = 1e8*np.sin(np.log10(t))
    W1=(Wb+0.02*A)*1e-26      
    W2=(Wb-0.02*A)*1e-26      

    w_12=V0*np.exp(-W1/kT)   
    w_21=V0*np.exp(-W2/kT)
    
    
    dP1_dt=- w_12*y1 + w_21*y2
    dP2_dt=+ w_12*y1 - w_21*y2
    dp_dt=[dP1_dt,dP2_dt]     
    return dp_dt
```

Of course, we then must modify the call to `odeint` to remove the `A` parameter as follows:

```
p=odeint(dpdt,[y1_0,1-y1_0],t,args=(Wb,V0,k*T))
```

Another approach is to write `dpdt` so that it expects a argument `A`, which is actually a function of `t`. E.g.

```
def dpdt(y,t,Wb,V0, A,kT):
    y1=y[0]
    y2=y[1]
    W1=(Wb+0.02*A(t))*1e-26      
    W2=(Wb-0.02*A(t))*1e-26      

    w_12=V0*np.exp(-W1/kT)   
    w_21=V0*np.exp(-W2/kT)
    
    
    dP1_dt=- w_12*y1 + w_21*y2
    dP2_dt=+ w_12*y1 - w_21*y2
    dp_dt=[dP1_dt,dP2_dt]     
    return dp_dt
```

Now you define a function `A`, and call `odeint` as follows:

```
def A(t):
    return 1e8*np.sin(np.log10(t))

p=odeint(dpdt,[y1_0,1-y1_0],t,args=(Wb,V0,A, k*T))
```